# EXCEL-Sum total surgerie duration of surgeries in the weekend and before or after working hours (with overlap)

Tags: excel, overlap, duration, countif, weekend

First I had to determine per specialty the total percentage of surgeries that started outside the regular working hours or in weekends.

The final line became:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((Table1[Start surgery]>TIME(17;0;0))*(WEEKDAY(Table1[Surgery date];2)<=5))+((Table1[Start surgery]<TIME(9;0;0))*(WEEKDAY(Table1[Surgery date];2)<=5))+(WEEKDAY(Table1[Surgery date];2)>=6))
```

Now I want to sum the total surgery time of these surgerys (outside working hours and in the weekend) in the G column (surgery duration). 
[image]

Help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Flag the items that matched your first criteria and then use that to calculate SUMIF on column G values.

Comment: Im trying to, but cant get the criteria to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have the SumProduct returning 1's and 0's for the correct slots, you just need to add another criterion of the surgery duration:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((((Table1[Start surgery]>TIME(17;0;0))*(WEEKDAY(Table1[Surgery date];2)<=5))+((Table1[Start surgery]<TIME(9;0;0))*(WEEKDAY(Table1[Surgery date];2)<=5))+(WEEKDAY(Table1[Surgery date];2)>=6))*(Table1[Surgery duration]))
```